# Drools 6.0 configure default dialect

Tags: drools, mvel, kie

I want to configure default dialect in drools to mvel.
I am currently using drools 6.0 ..

I tried using KnowledgeBuilderConfiguration (now deprecated), but it gives null pointer exception on setting drools.dialect.default to MVEL.

Comment: Might be this issue
https://issues.jboss.org/browse/DROOLS-475

Comment: setting drools.dialect.default to mvel (in lowercase) fixes the null pointer exception but I still dont know how to configure this using kie